# Confused about how to go about doing this program

Tags: vb.net, variables

The question is as follows. A customer needs a specific amount of paper. The charges on the paper are:

- .10 for single sheets.
- .055 per sheet in multiples of 100.
- .04 per sheet in multiples of 500.
- .03 per sheet in multiples of 1000.

I know you have to use mod division somewhere. I'm not sure if my variables are set up correctly, and my brain is about to melt. Sad right? haha. I would greatly appreciate some help with this. Cheers :)

```
Option Explicit On

Imports system

Module paperp
    Sub Main()

        Dim papercost As Double
        Dim onetpackage As Integer
        Dim fivehpackages As Integer
        Dim onehpackages As Integer
        Dim singlesheets As Integer

        Console.Writeline("Number of 1000 packages:")
        onetpackage = convert.toint32(Console.Readline())

        Console.Writeline("Number of 500 packages:")
        fivehpackages = convert.toint32(Console.Readline())

        Console.Writeline("Number of 100 packages:")
        onehpackages = convert.toint32(Console.Readline())

        Console.Writeline("Number of single sheets:")
        singlesheets = convert.toint32(console.Readline())

        Console.Out.Writeline("Number of 1000 packages:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(onetpackage)
        Console.Out.Writeline("Number of 500 packages:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(fivehpackages)
        Console.Out.Writeline("Number of 100 packages:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(onehpackages)
        Console.Out.Writeline("Number of single sheets:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(singlesheets)
        Console.Out.Writeline("Your total Cost is:")
        Console.Out.Writeline(papercost)

    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: We have to find the best possible price for a given sheet amount.

Comment: requested_amount = 3524;

1000_sheets = floor(requested_amount / 1000);
requested_amount = requested_amount % 1000;

500_sheets = floor(requested_amount / 500);
requested_amount = requested_amount % 500;

100_sheets = floor(requested_amount / 100);
requested_amount = requested_amount % 100;

1_sheets = requested_amount

Comment: Lets say a person needs 602 sheets, we now divide by 1000, then by 500, 100 saving those operations somewhere. You will be left with the amount of single sheets the person will have to buy. If division is between to integers, it will also return an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that code you just have to add the price per package:

```
papercost = _
  0.03 * 1000.0 * onetpackage + _
  0.04 * 500 * fivehpackages + _
  0.055 * 100 * onehpackages + _
  0.1 * singlesheets
```

However, to make the assignment make sense, I think that you should really just input the total number of sheets, and then calculate the number of packages. You could use the modulo to calculate the remaining sheets after calculating the number of packages, but it's just as simple to use substraction:

```
  onetpackage = Math.Floor(totalsheets / 1000)
  totalsheets -= onetpackage * 1000
```

Comment: So you are adding the papercost?

Answer (score 1):

Why not loop through each amount (e.g. 1000, 500, 100, 1), and with the no of sheets the user specifies in a variable, the logic would be like so:

Predefined vars: no_of_sheets (the users input), working_amount = no_of_sheets, current_index = 0, count = 0, amounts (array) = (1000, 500, 100, 1), costs = (0.03, 0.04, 0.055, 0.1), total = (0, 0, 0, 0)

```
While (working_amount > 0)
  if current_index < 4
    if (working_amount - amounts[current_index]) >= 0
      total[current_index]++
      working_amount = working_amount - amounts[current_index]
    else
      current_index++
    endif
  endif
endwhile
```

Now you have an array with the amounts of each block, e.g. an array of (1, 2, 3, 4) means 1 x 1000 sheets, 2 x 500, 3 x 100, 4 x 1

Then you can just multiply each bit by their price.

HOpe that helps.

Comment: Somewhere in the loop you need to subtract from working_amount.

Comment: @Chimera Right you are! Thank you.

Comment: Oh, and you have to make a special case for the single sheet index. Say you are left with 55 sheets. 55-1 = 54. Not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment question is an example of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), but fortunately a very simple variant of it.

You don't necessarily need to use the modulo operator - you can do it iteratively. Start off with the most expensive product (which provides the best price-per-item ratio) then "buy" as many as you can with your starting money (keep subtracting from the money until you can't afford it), then move on to the next afforable product and repeat until you can't afford anything.